# Firebug like application for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, firebug

Are there any applications equivalent to Firbug to work on Google Chrome?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ctrl-Shift-J will display the built in JavaScript console.

Plugins are coming soon

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions

Josh

Comment: You shouldn't accept an answer just because it's first. You should accept it because it is the best answer to your question.

Comment: @MatrixFrog - true dat .. but his answer (IMO) is still the best. The built in *Developer Tools* are equivalent to FireBug's tools -- for most general things. Definitely a good start.

Comment: The better answer is CTRL+SHIFT+I instead of CTRL+SHIFT+J. The J takes one to javascript console, while the I takes one to the HTML part. But CTRL+SHIFT+I has a tab for Console as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can embed [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) into your web pages to get Firebug features in non-FF browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has it's own DOM-explorer built in I believe.

Comment: Right-click on the document and select "Inspect element".

Answer (score 1):

There is an inspector built into WebKit (and thus Chrome) already, which does many of the same things as Firebug on Firefox.  Find it under the Page menu, Developer, "JavaScript Console", or right-click anything on a page and select "Inspect element" to get to that element in the inspector.

The "Resources" tab can show you a view similar to the "Network" view in Firebug.

[image: inspector screenshot]

Comment: Sounds nice, it just works on the markup level (i.e. I can select an item on the inspector window, and it will be highlighted on the page, but not vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

If don't like the **Chrome's console** you may use Firebug Lite bookmarklet : http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug Lite](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench?hl=en-gb) now exists as a native Chrome extension.

It has some limitations, but I much prefer it to the bookmarklet and hopefully the missing functionality will come in time.

Now we just need the plugins as well :D